# Regex-PHP: How can be find if the string equal to <br> with regex and not with ==

Tags: php, regex

How can i replace  a string with '' if string equel to `<br>` only with regex

I don't know regex, and I cant do this with regular expression (I know other ways, please don't write them)

Case 1 - replace because input equal to `<br>`:

```
 input== '<br>'  => result=''
```

Case 2 - not replace if input not equal to `<br>`:

```
 input==' xcx<br>dfd<br>' => result:' xcx<br>dfd<br>'
```

Thanks

Comment: You want to do it "with regex", "not with ==", even though you "don't know regex" and "cant do this with regular expression[sic]". Huh.

Comment: The better way is if (==) in your case

Comment: If you want **equal** use equals. Or use `===` instead. Or is this question about learning regex?

Comment: Sigh... **Regular expressions are NOT the tool for exact string comparison**. Between this and parsing HTML with regex, parsing HTML makes more sense (you really shouldn't be doing that either).

Comment: Unclear why Case 2? What if input is <br/> or <BR> etc. ?

Comment: Why do you need to use a regular expression if you can do it easily without? Are there some further requirements that you haven’t mentioned yet?

Comment: I deleted my answer; I hope the downvoters are happy. At the time I posted this answer, the OP never stated that **regex was compulsory** for the function he was using to replace `<br>`, and the question seemed like, as the others say, asking how to use regex to do replacements based on **exact string comparisons** when **non-regex solutions were acceptable/preferred**.

Comment: @Gumbo: See my above comment, and the two -1 answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do:

```
$result = preg_replace('/^<br>$/', '', $input);
```

Explanation:

```
^    : Start anchor
<br> : A literal <br>
$    : End anchor
```

The regex is just the string you want to match placed in between the start and end anchor. The anchors are important, without them you'll end up replacing `<br>` in string that has `<br>` as its substring.

Answer (score 3):

```
$string = preg_replace('~^<br>$~', '', $string);
```

`^` denotes the start of a string, `$` the end. But what's the point? Doing a comparison is much more appropriate:

```
if ('<br>' === $string) {
    $string = '';
}
```

Comment: Maybe there is som built in regex replace tool he needs to use to handle input and he might not be able to code his own solution ;)

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
$input = '<br>';
if ($input == '<br>') {
    $result = '';
}

echo $result; // Output: (nothing)


$input = ' xcx<br>dfd<br>';
if ($input == '<br>') {
    $result = '';
}

echo $result; // Output:  xcx<br>dfd<br>
?>
```

Comment: He specifically asked how to do this with regex and no other way.

Comment: Regex! not == , I have to use it- in some function that have only regex parameter

Comment: @Yosef: From your question the only thing we understand is you want to replace `<br>` with blank...

Comment: (a) The question was so incoherent that I couldn't tell. The phrase "I cant do this with regular expression" was part of it. (b) Regex is definitely the wrong tool for this job.